# If $G$ is a vector field, and $G = ∇g$ for some function $g$, what would line integral $G · ds$ have to be?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, line-integrals

> If $G$ is a vector field, and $G = ∇g$ for some function $g$, what would line integral $G · ds$ have to be? (Hint: Think of c as a curve whose ending point is the same as its starting point).

Since $c$ has same starting and end point it could be a circle
$c(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$, $t ∈ [0,2\pi]$.
So by fundamental theorem of line integrals integral of 
 $$G · ds = g(c(2\pi)) - g(c(0)) 
= g(1,0)-g(1,0)
= 0$$
This doesn't seem right. Please correct me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. It is a consequence of the [gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem).

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was wrong!